# Is it possible to launch containing app from iOS 8 keyboard extension with full access enabled?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I know the Settings app can be launched, but can the containing app be launched from the keyboard extension?

Comment: It is possible, but it is hackish (the apple provided method is explicitly disallowed for keyboards), and it doesn't seem to work in the latest beta (8.3).

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind explaining or linking to hackish method?